# Traefik V2.2.1 - All services except Traefik service returns [NET :: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID] and uses [TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT]

Tags: docker, ssl, traefik

I decided to upgrade the version of traefik from 1.7.x to 2.2.1.
So I followed the guidelines of the solution above (https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/8f124039a9bd3801f0caf3c01c3601fb) so that traefik in version 2.2.1 would work.
Traefik v2.2.1 worked and correctly redirected the http port to https.
However, the whoami service redirects from the http port to https but displays the following message:

```
WHOAMI return

NET :: ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID
TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT
```

```
############################################
Problem
############################################
Returns - Whoami Address / Service

C: \ Windows \ system32> curl http://whoami.ehpop.com.br/
Moved Permanently


C: \ Windows \ system32> curl https://whoami.ehpop.com.br/
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html
curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
not match the domain name in the URL).
If you would like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
the -k (or --insecure) option.

C: \ Windows \ system32> curl https://whoami.ehpop.com.br/ -k
Hostname: 420fd35c2aff
IP: 127.0.0.1
IP: 172.23.0.2
RemoteAddr: 172.23.0.5:48334
GET / HTTP / 1.1
Host: whoami.ehpop.com.br
User-Agent: curl / 7.39.0
Accept: * / *
Accept-Encoding: gzip
X-Forwarded-For: 177.223.109.184
X-Forwarded-Host: whoami.ehpop.com.br
X-Forwarded-Port: 443
X-Forwarded-Proto: https
X-Forwarded-Server: ffb0f2160d14
X-Real-Ip: 177.223.109.184
```

```
############################################
OK
############################################
Returns for access to the traefik monitor

C: \ Windows \ system32> curl http://traefik.ehpop.com.br --user admin
Enter host password for user 'admin':
Moved Permanently

C: \ Windows \ system32> curl https://traefik.ehpop.com.br --user admin
Enter host password for user 'admin':
<a href="/dashboard/"> Found </a>.
```

```
############################################
Files and settings I'm using:
############################################
```

```
############################################
[Traefik v2.] - docker-compose.yml with httpChallenge
############################################

version: '3.7'

services:
  traefik:
    image: traefik:v2.2
    container_name: traefik
    restart: unless-stopped
    security_opt:
      - no-new-privileges:true
    networks:
      - proxy
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    volumes:
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
      - ./traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
      - ./acme.json:/acme.json
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=admin:$$password"

      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.rule=Host(`traefik.ehpop.com.br`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.entrypoints=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"

      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefik.ehpop.com.br`)"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=https"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"

      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
      - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
      - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
      - "traefik.http.services.traefik.loadbalancer.server.port=8080"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

```
############################################
[Traefik v2.] - traefik.yml with httpChallenge
############################################

api:
  dashboard: true

# Writing Logs to a File, in JSON
log:
  level: DEBUG
  filePath: "log-file.log"
  format: json

# Configuring a buffer of 100 lines
accessLog:
  filePath: "log-access.log"
  bufferingSize: 100  

entryPoints:
  http:
    address: ":80"
  https:
    address: ":443"

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false

certificatesResolvers:
  http:
    acme:
      email: naugustijr@gmail.com
      storage: acme.json
      httpChallenge:
        entryPoint: http
```

```
############################################
[Traefik v2.] - whoami - docker-compose.yml
############################################

version: '3.7'

services:
    whoami:
      image: containous/whoami
      container_name: whoami
      restart: unless-stopped
      security_opt:
        - no-new-privileges:true
      networks:
        - proxy
      volumes:
        - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
        - ./data:/data
      labels:
        - "traefik.enable=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`, `www.whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
        - "traefik.http.middlewares.whoami-https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true"

        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.middlewares=whoami-https-redirect"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.entrypoints=https"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`, `www.whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.tls=true"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.tls.certresolver=http"
        - "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.service=whoami"
        - "traefik.http.services.whoami.loadbalancer.server.port=80"
        - "traefik.docker.network=proxy"

networks:
  proxy:
    external: true
```

I would like to know how to resolve this issue.
I looked at the traefik documentation but found no errors.

Comment: I updated Traefik config for v2.9.9 https://gist.github.com/fatihyildizhan/8f124039a9bd3801f0caf3c01c3601fb This could be a solution for your feature problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed this section

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`, `www.whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`, `www.whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
```

for this one

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami-secure.rule=Host(`whoami.ehpop.com.br`)"
```

and it worked!

Comment: You already solved the problem. I think there is a problem due to 2nd-degree subdomain.